# Removing an item from a select box depending on the value of the selectbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code that loop the number of available rooms.

```
<div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <?php
         $option = [];
         $value_3 = isset($rooms['total_available_room']) ? 
         $rooms['total_available_room'] : 0;

           for ($i=0; $i <= $value_3; $i++) {
              $option[$i] = $i;
           }
        ?>

{{ Form::label('rooms', 'No. of rooms: ',['style' => 'color:black']) }}
{{ Form::select('n_rooms', $option, null, ['required', 'tabindex' => '10', 'id' => 'selectBox']) }}
</div>

<div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:removeItem()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>
```

Now how do I remove the decrease the number of available room after the user click on the book button. For example if the value of the select is 4 and the available room is 7, after the button click the value of the select should be 0-3.

```
    function removeItem()
  {
     $("#selectBox $option[0] - $option[]").remove();
  }
```

How do I do this properly?

**Added rendered HTML**

```
                      <tr class="table-products-list pos-center">
                      <td class="products-image-table" style="padding-top:0px"><img alt="Products Image 1" src="http://localhost/site/public/storage/cover_images/Standard-room_1543751302.jpg" class="img-responsive"></td>
                      <td class="title-table">
                          <div class="room-details-list clearfix">
                              <div class="pull-left">
                                  <h5>Standard Room</h5>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pull-left room-rating">
                                  <ul>
                                      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                      <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                                      <li><i class="fa fa-star inactive"></i></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list-room-icons clearfix">
                              <ul>
                                  <li title="Free Wifi"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i></li>
                                  <li title="Parking Space"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></li>
                                  <li title="Airconditioned Room"><i class="fa fa-snowflake-o"></i></li>
                                  <li title="Televisions"><i class="fa fa-television"></i></li>
                                  <li title="Shower"><i class="fa fa-shower"></i></li>
                                  <li title="Breakfast"><i class="fa fa-spoon"></i></li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                          <p style="margin:0px"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a class="active-color" href="standard">[...]</a> </p>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                                  <label for="adult" style="color:black">No. of Adult: </label>
                                  <select required tabindex="9" name="n_adult"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                                  <label for="children" style="color:black">No. of Children: </label>
                                  <select required tabindex="10" name="n_children"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
                              </div>

                              <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                                  <label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
                                  <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option></select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <h3>P2000</h3>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="pull-right">
                              <h4 style="color:red">7 Rooms Available</h4>
                          </div>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <div class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK
                                  </span></a></div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: may you add the rendered html?

Comment: One of many possibilities: `$('#selectBox option').eq(2).remove();` removes the third `<option>`.

Comment: @ChrisG Yours is working, to remove the third option. But how do I minus the selected option to itself then output the remaining?

Comment: @gaetanoM what do you mean rendered html? sorry I don't understand that term, do you mean a screen shot of the page?

Comment: Get the index of the selected option and remove it.

Comment: @Rei Get the html fragment from the browser: ctrl+u and copy the rendered part.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `minus the selected option to itself`

Comment: @ChrisG If the user select 1 in the option, and the values of select is 1-7. it should minus 1 to 7. The remaining option should only be 1-6

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. Post the final HTML.

Comment: @gaetanoM  Sorry for the delay, I added the rendered html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire an event handler to the select's change event.

When that event fires calculate the difference between the total number of rooms available and the user's selected option.

Hide all options with a value greater than this difference and show all others.

Assuming the last option will always be the greatest number of rooms this snippet will work.

```js
$('#selectBoxStandard').change(function() {
  var sel = $(this);
  var opts = this.options;
  var max = parseInt(opts[opts.length - 1].value);
  var val = parseInt($(sel).val());
  var remaining = max - val;
  $(opts).each(function(i, e) {
    if (parseInt($(e).val()) <= remaining) {
      $(e).show();
    } else {
      $(e).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

  <label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
  <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```